# Extra records appear in pytable table when created/appended from numpy zero recarray

Tags: python, numpy, pytables

(this question has been modified by the original author and the sample code modified so that you can run it on your machine)

I am loading time series data into pytables (~2 million rows, 23 columns of mostly float values in this test case).  I would also like to create a corresponding table in the same pytable file with the same number of rows and columns and column names but with int8 data types to be used as a quality control 'mask'. To do this I am retrieving column names and row count information from the data table and using this to create numpy zero record arrays which are used to create/append to the quality control pytable table.

The problem occurs when I append the numpy zero record arrays to the new 'mask' pytable.  Even though the numpy zero record arrays that are used to create/append to the pytable are the correct size - the resulting pytable is considerably larger than expected - with more rows in the pytable then had been appended from the numpy recarray.

The following runnable example code demonstrates the problem.  It creates a pytable and appends numpy zero recarrays to the table with the expectation of creating a table with 'nrows' of records with zero values.  The resulting pytable has more rows than expected when viewed with Vitables

I am not sure where these extra data rows are coming from?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Using python 2.7.2, pytables 2.3.1, numpy 1.6.1.1

```
import tables 
import numpy as np
import string as str

Storename   = 'Test.h5'
Storetitle  = 'Test'
PathList    = ['Lvl0','Lvl1']
Tablename   = 'Data'

storeq = tables.openFile(Storename, mode='a', title= Storetitle)

for ix, agroup in enumerate(PathList):
   mypath0 =  '/'+str.strip('/'.join(PathList[0:ix]))
   mypath1 =  '/'+str.strip('/'.join(PathList[0:ix+1]))      
   try:  
      storeq.getNode(mypath1)
   except(tables.exceptions.NoSuchNodeError):        
      storeq.createGroup(mypath0,PathList[ix]) 

pathq = mypath1
qtable = None  

tfields = ['DateTime','f0','f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8','f9']
nfields = 11

tformats = ['int64', 'int8', 'int8', 'int8', 'int8', 'int8', 
            'int8', 'int8', 'int8', 'int8', 'int8']

nrows = 2122387
rowchunk = 100000
rowsteps, rowrem = divmod(nrows, rowchunk)

for ix in range(rowsteps):        
  fillarray = np.zeros((rowchunk,nfields), {'names': tfields, 'formats': tformats})
  if qtable==None:
      print('create')      
      qtable    = storeq.createTable(pathq, Tablename, fillarray)       
      qtable.flush()
  else:
      print('append :', ix, fillarray.shape)  
      qtable.append(fillarray)
      qtable.flush()

if rowrem > 0:
  fillarray = np.zeros((rowrem,nfields), {'names': tfields, 'formats': tformats})
  if ix == 0:
     print('create')      
     qtable  = storeq.createTable(pathq,Tablename, fillarray)       
     qtable.flush()
  else:
     print('append :', rowrem, fillarray.shape)  
     qtable.append(fillarray)
     qtable.flush()


qtable.close()
storeq.close()
```

The following is the print statement output created when the numpy zero recarrays are written to the quality control pytable.

```
create
('append :', 1, (100000, 26))
('append :', 2, (100000, 26))
('append :', 3, (100000, 26))
('append :', 4, (100000, 26))
('append :', 5, (100000, 26))
('append :', 6, (100000, 26))
('append :', 7, (100000, 26))
('append :', 8, (100000, 26))
('append :', 9, (100000, 26))
('append :', 10, (100000, 26))
('append :', 11, (100000, 26))
('append :', 12, (100000, 26))
('append :', 13, (100000, 26))
('append :', 14, (100000, 26))
('append :', 15, (100000, 26))
('append :', 16, (100000, 26))
('append :', 17, (100000, 26))
('append :', 18, (100000, 26))
('append :', 19, (100000, 26))
('append :', 20, (100000, 26))
('append :', 22387, (22387, 26))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the age of the question, I guess the author already has the answer... But just in case, here is mine (not tested):

On line 45 of your example code, you create a structured array of shape `(rowchunk, nfields)`: this is wrong because structured array must be 1D (number of rows), the number, names and formats of fields being set by the `dtype` argument.

Hence you should use something like

```
fillarray = np.zeros(rowchunk, dtype={'names': tfields, 'formats': tformats})
```